# Can't Upload A Custom Template To TFS 2018

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, process

I'm trying to upload a new custom template to TFS 2018 Versión 16.122.27102.1.

In the documentation showed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?view=vsts

In Visual Studio in the tab called: **team** -> **project collection settings** -> **process template manager**

It opens a new window with the options to upload, download, make default, delete.

But when I click on it, the process template manager in Visual Studio it redirects me to the web portal of TFS, the process section.

I want to interact with the window showed in the documentation, since I can't upload a new custom process using the web portal, it throws a generic error when I try to upload.

Comment: The visual studio upload mechanism is past. You'll need to fix the upload issue on the portal. Check the event viewer on the server's Windows Event Viewer for more details.

Comment: Thanks man, i'll try checking that out.

Comment: Which version of VS do you use?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.7.5 @ShaykiAbramczyk

Comment: Did you try in another computer? on TFS 2018 you should be able to manage the templates in VS.

Comment: This is the problem that I have at the web portal:

When I try to upload a custom process template, which must be in a zip file:

https://imgur.com/Sou3NfW

It throws this super generic error message, sorry if it is in spanish, I changed the lenguage to english but aparently that message doesn't change:

https://imgur.com/COsowc2

I'm part of the Admins of that collection, I have the permission to modify the process,the template is only slightly modified, but the error message is so generic and I believe i did everything the documentation mentioned.
@ShaykiAbramczyk thanks.

Comment: @JohnWick can you translate the error?

Comment: It says "You can't update a system process, Obtain more information about process customization" @ShaykiAbramczyk

Comment: @JohnWick do you try to upload process with name Agile/Scrum/CMMI?

Comment: No, I change the name using the process template editor, on VS community, @ShaykiAbramczyk what I was thinking is that I have to make more changes, adding a new WIT, or changing the version or something like that, do you have a custom template lying around that i can use to check if that one works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help by the Developer Community at Visual Studio, the answer was really simple, I needed to change the name of the template but also the **VERSION** of it. 
I was changing a ton of stuff about the template, name, WIT's, etc. But if you don't change the **VERSION** of the template pretty much manually you can't upload it.
Thank you very much to all the people that helped me.